# Removing Backend pools and load balancer rules before creating another

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have terraform script which creates Backend address pools and Loadbalancer rules in Loadbalancer in resource group. These tasks are included in Azure-pipeline. FOr the first time I run the pipeline.Its creating properly. If I run the pipeline for the second time. Its not updating the existing one .Its keeping the Backend address pools and Loadbalancer rules which are created by previous release and adding the extra Backend address pools and Loadbalancer rules for this release which is causing duplicates in Backend address pools and Loadbalancer rules. Any suggestions on this please

```
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "example" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                = "BackEndAddressPool"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "example" {
  resource_group_name            = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                           = "LBRule"
  protocol                       = "All"
  frontend_port                  = 0
  backend_port                   = 0
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "PublicIPAddress"
  enable_floating_ip             = true
  backend_address_pool_id        = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example
}
```

[image: This is how am getting]

Comment: You could add a `terraform destroy --target=azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example` on your pipeline before you do the `terraform apply` that will guarantee removal before creating one one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely happening because the Terraform state file is being lost between pipeline runs.

> By default, Terraform stores state locally in a file named terraform.tfstate. When working with Terraform in a team, use of a local file makes Terraform usage complicated because each user must make sure they always have the latest state data before running Terraform and make sure that nobody else runs Terraform at the same time.
>   With remote state, Terraform writes the state data to a remote data store, which can then be shared between all members of a team. Terraform supports storing state in Terraform Cloud, HashiCorp Consul, Amazon S3, Alibaba Cloud OSS, and more.
>
> Remote state is a feature of backends. Configuring and using remote backends is easy and you can get started with remote state quickly. If you then want to migrate back to using local state, backends make that easy as well.

You will want to configure [Remote State storage](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html) to keep the state. Here is an example using Azure Blob Storage:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "StorageAccount-ResourceGroup"
    storage_account_name = "abcd1234"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "prod.terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

> Stores the state as a Blob with the given Key within the Blob Container within the Blob Storage Account. This backend also supports state locking and consistency checking via native capabilities of Azure Blob Storage.

This is more completely described in the [azurerm Terraform backend docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/azurerm.html).

Microsoft also provides a [Tutorial: Store Terraform state in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/store-state-in-azure-storage), which goes through the setup step by step.

Comment: Do I need to add this in my main.tf before baackendpools creation?

Comment: It has to be in your root module, the one where you run terraform apply. It doesn't necessarily have to be in main.tf. It can be in any .tf file in the same directory or it can be generated by a tool like Terragrunt.

Comment: I have tried it ...it's working for the first time next time it's creating extra backend pools again.

Comment: If you run the tutorial in a pipeline you'll get new storage accounts and backends as well. You should create the backend with the script from the tutorial once and then store an reuse the same values of RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, CONTAINER_NAME, and ACCOUNT_KEY in the pipelines. Make sure to protect ACCOUNT_KEY using something like Azure Key Vault as recommended in the tutorial.

Comment: @ Alain O' Dea I have tried the tuturiol.. Its giving me extra VMs under each backend addresspool. I have attached am image in my question to show how am getting .Please check .

Comment: You only need the backend piece from the tutorial. The page I linked to does not create VMs and the code you shared does not create VMs either. Terraform runs **all** TF files in the current working directory. Are there any other TF files in the same directory unrelated to what you are attempting here?