# Getting extra VMs under backend pools of load balancer for each pipeline run in azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Release pipeline in terraform which has Terraform init,plan and apply tasks. For the first time of running pipeline. Everything is creating as expected but when I rerun the pipeline then its adding extra VM nics under backend pools of load balancer [![This is how am getting][1]][1]

nodecount is given while running the pipeline

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "db1" {
  count                       = nodecount >= "2" ? 1: 0
  network_interface_id        = azurerm_network_interface.db[0].id
  ip_configuration_name       = "ipconfig-${element(split(":",var.systemname),0)}"
  backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_adress_pool.db[0].id
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.db]
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "db2" {
  count                       = nodecount >= "2" ? 1: 0
  network_interface_id        = azurerm_network_interface.db[1].id
  ip_configuration_name       = "ipconfig-${element(split(":",var.systemname),0)}"
  backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_adress_pool.db[0].id
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.db]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "db3" {
  count                       = nodecount >= "4" ? 1: 0
  network_interface_id        = azurerm_network_interface.db[2].id
  ip_configuration_name       = "ipconfig-${element(split(":",var.systemname),1)}"
  backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_adress_pool.db[1].id
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.db]
} 
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "db4" {
  count                       = nodecount >= "4" ? 1: 0
  network_interface_id        = azurerm_network_interface.db[3].id
  ip_configuration_name       = "ipconfig-${element(split(":",var.systemname),1)}"
  backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_adress_pool.db[1].id
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.db]
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "db5" {
  count                       = nodecount >= "6" ? 1: 0
  network_interface_id        = azurerm_network_interface.db[4].id
  ip_configuration_name       = "ipconfig-${element(split(":",var.systemname),2)}"
  backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_adress_pool.db[2].id
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.db]
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "db6" {
  count                       = nodecount >= "6" ? 1: 0
  network_interface_id        = azurerm_network_interface.db[5].id
  ip_configuration_name       = "ipconfig-${element(split(":",var.systemname),2)}"
  backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_adress_pool.db[2].id
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.db]
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "db7" {
  count                       = nodecount >= "8" ? 1: 0
  network_interface_id        = azurerm_network_interface.db[6].id
  ip_configuration_name       = "ipconfig-${element(split(":",var.systemname),3)}"
  backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_adress_pool.db[3].id
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.db]
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "db8" {
  count                       = nodecount >= "8" ? 1: 0
  network_interface_id        = azurerm_network_interface.db[7].id
  ip_configuration_name       = "ipconfig-${element(split(":",var.systemname),3)}"
  backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_adress_pool.db[3].id
  depends_on                  = [azurerm_network_interface.db]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicated with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62248659/removing-backend-pools-and-load-balancer-rules-before-creating-another)?

Comment: @Nancy Xiong Question is for same purpose but I have given irrelavent code..Fortunately that solved another issue..but this issue is still pending..So posted another question with correct code